# Why does this well-known simple code with package "dygraph" not work?

Tags: r, time-series, dygraphs

Function `dygraph` supports time-series object. In several examples of web resource, the function had often been used with built-in time-series `nhtemp` data. However, this code returned the below error in my case. What's wrong? Please help me.

```
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(dygraphs)

nhtemp %>% dygraph(main = "New Haven Temperatures") %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
```

> Error in dygraph(., main = "New Haven Temperatures") : Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'

Comment: try putting a comma before ```main``` such as ```dygraph(., main = "New Haven Temperatures")```. It would be easier to help you with a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with R.3.6.0 and dygraphs package version 1.1.1.6.
Try updating the package version.